# Cascading Combobox - WinForms with added values

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am in the process of creating a winform that has cascading values between two comboboxs, the user selected the category from a combobox and then the itemcombobox will display the corresponding values.

I have come up with the code below:

```
    private void categorycombo_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { 
        string category = categorycombo.GetItemText(categorycombo.SelectedItem);
        if (category == "BUS")
        {
            itemcombo.Items.Add("BLUESTAR");
            itemcombo.Items.Add("FIRSTBUS");
        }
        else if (category == "FERRY")
        {
            itemcombo.Items.Add("ISLE OF WIGHT FERRY");
            itemcombo.Items.Add("HYTHE FERRY");
        }
        else (category == "RAIL")
        {
            itemcombo.Items.Add("SW RAIL");
            itemcombo.Items.Add("VIRGIN RAIL");
        }
    }
```

My Code looks logical (For a novice) but I am wondering why it will not work.

VS2015 seems to like the code and no errors show.

The category box is coded like:

```
        categorycombo.Items.Add("BUS");
        categorycombo.Items.Add("FERRY");
        categorycombo.Items.Add("RAIL");
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? Does nothing show up in this second combobox? One thing I notice from the above is that you don't clear the combobox, so everytime you change the first one, you'll be adding more options to the second combobox.

Comment: Nothing shows in the second combobox, I have a cleardata function that I run when the form completes/reset.

Comment: There is a small error in the code. The last statement should be `else if` not `else`. That would generally give you a compiler error. With the `if` put in, the code actually works for me.

Comment: all i seem to get is a blank box when I selected the itemcombo

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is to make sure that `categorycombo`'s `SelectedIndexChanged` event is subscribed to `categorycombo_SelectedIndexChanged`. Click on the `categorycombo` and where you set its properties, click the lightning bolt icon and ensure that method name is next to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

Comment: How `else (category == "RAIL")` can work? Is there a missing `if`?

Comment: Just a tip:  for this sort of behavior, I prefer the `SelectionChangeCommitted` method, as it only fires when the item is clicked.  `SelectedIndexChanged` fires _every time_ the property changes, including you setting the value in code.  Sometimes that can be disruptive or have unintended side-effects.

Comment: Perfect matthew_b!

Comment: DonBoitnott - good idea, I have changed it to ChangeCommitted and its working a treat! Thank you guys!